# load ByteArray type image file to picture box using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `byte[]` type picture file that saved in sql image field, the image will shows in DGV(DataGridView), now I try to display the image in picture box on the form from currentRow( DataGridViewRow) object and I got the error "Unable to cast object of type `System.String` to type `System.Byte[]`.", how should I do it ? can someone help ! thanks

```
private void DGV_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        private DataGridViewRow currentRow = new DataGridViewRow();
        //Get current row object
        currentRow = DGV.Rows[DGV.CurrentRow.Index];
        //Display Fields Detail on the form
        DisplayFields(currentRow);
    }

private void DisplayFields(DataGridViewRow row)  
    {  
        this.tbxItemGUID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        //row.Celles[1] contained byte[] image file which saved in sql image field
        //how can I display image in picture box
        this.pictureBox.image = (byte[])row.Cells[1].Value;
    }
```

Comment: format the snippet properly,

Comment: Please read your own code comment above `byte[] picture = (byte[])row.Cells[5].Value;` and then compare what that comments says with what you have written there in your code line...  o_O

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I solved the problem already, this is how I did it..please let me know if there is better way.

private void DGV_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    private DataGridViewRow currentRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    //Get current row object
    currentRow = DGV.Rows[DGV.CurrentRow.Index];
    //Display Fields Detail on the form
    DisplayFields(currentRow);
}
```

private void DisplayFields(DataGridViewRow row)
    {

```
    this.tbxItemGUID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();  
    byte[] picture = new byte[0];
    picture = (byte[])row.Cells[1].Value;
    this.PictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(picture));
 }
```